# Encode URL and Text for custom Pin It button

Tags: php

So I'm using the custom pinterest button builder and it spits out and anchor that looks like this:

```
<a href="//gb.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F&media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg&description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="none">
```

The url is composed of a few parameters, which are url, media and description.

I want to replace each parameter with my own, using php in wordpress.

I'd like something along the lines of this:

```
<a href="//gb.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo $url; ?>&media=<?php echo $url; ?>&description=<?php the_title(); ?>" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="none">
```

If you look at pinterests example the url and description are encoded to replace spaces and special characters with %20 or other % type replacements.

So, how do I encode a url like:

```
http://lart.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/30d5466ca31411e3863812695239df89_8.jpg
```

And text like:
This is a description

so pinterest will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `urlencode()`. Pay attention to the parameters in `the_title()`:

```
<a href="//gb.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>&media=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>&description=<?php echo urlencode(the_title(null,null,false)); ?>" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="none">
```

Comment: Great, I figured as much, I was unsure if I was to use rawurlencode or urlencode though or even if I was on the right track. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Oh yea, could I just `get_the_title();` instead and ignore the parameters?

Comment: @UzumakiDev: No `the_title()` will automatically `echo` if the 3rd parameter is not set to `false`, so you can't send it through `urlencode()`.